# Can I install an outlet near the ceiling of a pavilion?

Tags: receptacle

I'm in the process of building a pavilion.  I'm doing the work myself.  We are hanging a TV from the ceiling.  I was planning on installing an outlet near the ceiling so I can plug in the TV.  However, I've seen conflicting height requirements.  I've seen some say that the maximum height from grade is 6'6" for an outlet.  Then I've seen other say that is only for switches, not outlets. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but I'm sure I've seen outlets far higher than that (e.g. for clocks). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a plain outlet anywhere you please.

The reason this is an issue is that in certain locations, the outlet needs to be GFCI protected.  And **you can't put a GFCI test/reset button that high**.

So **if GFCI protection is even required**, take advantage of a feature of almost every GFCI device, called "Load", which allows it to protect plain devices downstream.  That is obvious when dealing with GFCI+breakers or GFCI-only ("deadfront") devices.  But GFCI+receptacle devices can do it too!   So you just install one of those in an accessible location, and you're all set.